# Who owns a Google AdSense account?

Tags: adsense

Is there a way to tell who own a Google AdSense account by the java-script on the page? the google_ad_client or google_ad_slot?

One of our sites was hacked and Google AdSense was placed on the pages. We would like to get as much information about the account and have Google shut it down, perhaps pursue legal options against the hacker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send google the code that they added to the pages. Google can look at who owns the account by the ID in the code.